# Can someone please explain the ratio test to me please?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with the steps of the ratio test. 
So it's from $1$ to $\infty$ and $\dfrac{17^n}{n!}$. I there's division involved to find $r$, but what do we divide?

Comment: To start: divide $n+1$-st term to $n$-th term. For practice you want to divide say 11-th by 10th. OR 21st to 20th, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're given a series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {17^n}{n!}$$
Now, the ratio test says that...

> Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, consider $$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$ If $L<1$, then the series converges, and if $L>1$, the series diverges.

So, looking at the statement of the ratio test, in our case we have $a_n=\frac{17^n}{n!}$. How do we proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

LEt $a_n = \frac{ 17^n}{n!}$. The ratio test says that if

$$ \lim | \frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n} | < 1, \sum a_n \; \text{converges}, $$

and diverges if the lim is $>1$ and it is inconclusive if the lim $=1$. As for your example,

$$ \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{17^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{17^n} = \frac{17}{n+1} \to 0$$

Hence, the series converges

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: People frown upon solving other people's homework.

Comment: Como saber si es tarea o no este problema. Mi deber es ayudar, y no confundir. Personas aqui dan pistas que son muy confusas para lo que preguntan, y terminan confundiendolos mas. Que harias tu en una situacion en la cual estas muy confundido por un problema $X$, y alguien te da una pista que te confunde aun mas? Es muy frustante esa situacion. Quizas no la has experimentado, o quizas si. Yo pienso que debemos siempre pensar en el otro.